How to fix Drush related error: Error: Undefined constant PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY
I installed Composer 2.8.2 and Drush 13.3.3.0 in vscode on Windows and gitcloned a Pantheon hosted Drupal 10.4.0 site to a folder on my PC.
In vscode integrated terminal I can display the Drush version for this git cloned folder using:
./vendor/bin/drush --version
Drush Commandline Tool 13.3.3.0

..however when I run ./vendor/bin/drush status I get the below error
$ ./vendor/bin/drush status
Error: Undefined constant PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY in C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\web\core\modules\mysql\src\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection.php on line 140 #0 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Database.php(460): Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection::open()
#1 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Database.php(191): Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection()
#2 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Boot\DrupalBoot8.php(162): Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection()
#3 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Boot\BootstrapManager.php(272): Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot8->bootstrapDrupalDatabaseValidate()
#4 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Boot\BootstrapManager.php(395): Drush\Boot\BootstrapManager->bootstrapValidate()
#5 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Boot\BootstrapManager.php(332): Drush\Boot\BootstrapManager->bootstrapMax()
#6 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Boot\BootstrapManager.php(304): Drush\Boot\BootstrapManager->bootstrapToPhaseIndex()
#7 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Boot\BootstrapHook.php(36): Drush\Boot\BootstrapManager->bootstrapToPhase()
#8 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher.php(44): Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize()
#9 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher.php(36): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->doInitializeHook()
#10 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher.php(29): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook()
#11 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\CommandProcessor.php(145): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize()   
#12 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\AnnotatedCommand.php(376): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook()
#13 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(292): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize()
#14 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1096): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#15 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(324): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#16 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(175): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#17 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php(110): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#18 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php(40): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun()
#19 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php(140): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run()
#20 C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\vendor\bin\drush.php(119): include('...')
#21 {main}
Error: Undefined constant PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY in Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection::open() (line 140 of C:\Users\hcann\vscode-sites\demo-drupal-sites\web\core\modules\mysql\src\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection.php).
 [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.

Composer is running PHP 8.3.13 and the Drupal 10.4.0 site runs 8.3.14
New to using Drush so hopefully someone can help direct me.
Thanks

You need to install an appropriate PHP PDO-MySQL extension for your platform. This is one of the reasons tools like DDEV and Lando are so popular, because they'll configure all of this out of the box for you.

This is essentially a missing platform requirement.

Thanks. I resolved that error and now when I run drush status I get this new error [preflight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed. What's strange is it appears to be Pantheon specific because I have drush running fine on different hosting with same site/composer/drush versions.

Error [preflight] Package "drupal/core" is not installed Resolved ./vendor/drush/drush/drush status works. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76584573/package-drupal-core-is-not-installed - may help someone else
